# Entendimento sobre o conteúdo de elementos de array

Tags: javascript, array

```
const funcs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    funcs.push(function(){
        console.log(i);
    });
}

funcs[2]();
funcs[8]();
```

Gostaria de entender o porque do resultado, `funcs[2]()` e `funcs[8]()`, serem `2` e `8`.

Se o índice inicia em 0, os retornos não deveriam serem `1` e `7`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 7):

Não deveria, na verdade você deveria explicar porque acha que deveria dar 1 e 7.

Se colocarmos pra imprimir qual é o índice do último elemento do *array* ele bate com o valor que manda imprimir dentro da função:

```js
const funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs.push(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
    console.log(funcs.length - 1, i);
}
console.log(funcs.length);
funcs[2]();
funcs[8]();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Index0.js).

Estou pegando o último índice disponível pegando o valor da propriedade `length` do *array*. Faço a subtração porque o último elemento é sempre um índice anterior ao tamanho, afinal o primeiro elemento do *array* é de índice 0, então o segundo é o índice 1 e assim por diante. Note que ele termina em 9 apesar de ter 10 elementos no *array*

Com isso podemos ver que o valor de `i` é sempre igual ao valor do índice que a função foi adicionada ao *array*.

Talvez tenha esquecido nessa parte que o *array* começa em 0 e não em 1.

Answer (score 7):

O índice realmente inicia no `0`, porém a questão é que no loop, você está atribuindo uma função que irá dar um `console.log` no índice atual, logo, qualquer um que você chamar, será igual ao índice dele mesmo:

```
funcs[0](); // mostra 0
funcs[1](); // mostra 1
funcs[2](); // mostra 2
...
funcs[9](); // mostra 9
```

Talvez fique mais fácil se você visualizar assim:

```js
const funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log("funcs["+i+"] vai mostrar: " + i);
    funcs.push(function(){
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```